# Image resize error using intervention in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am using intervention image to resize image and then save it to a destination folder. But its not working for me. I am getting error like, "Image source not readable". 
Pls see the below code:

```
 $image_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
 $thumbName      =   'thumb_'.  $image_name;
 $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/';
 $thumbdestinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/thumbnails/';
 $imgUrl = URL::to('/').'/public/uploads/'.$image_name;
 $thumbUrl = URL::to('/').'/public/uploads/thumbnails/'.$image_name;

  $upload_success = $file->move( $destinationPath, $image_name);
if ($upload_success) {
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->fit('120','120')->save($thumbdestinationPath );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the name of image:

```
if ($upload_success) {
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->fit('120','120')->save($thumbdestinationPath . $image_name );
}
```